# Output disappearing after half execution of main() in C

Tags: c, file, aes

I have a text file "my.txt". I want to read first 16 bytes from the text file and then perform the aes operation of key expansion and cipher algorithm on the data. After this, the next 16 bytes are to be encrypted. I run the following code but during execution, after entering the key in hexadecimal the output screen just disappears. I dont understand why is this so? Same work of file reading was successfully running in a separate program but after incorporating it into my AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) program, the file portion of the program does not execute. Infact the screen disappears after taking key from user. Please help me on this.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    // The number of columns comprising a state in AES. This is a constant in AES. //Value=4

    #define Nb 4

    // The number of rounds in AES Cipher. It is simply initiated to zero. The actual value is recieved in the program.

    int Nr=0;

    // The number of 32 bit words in the key. It is simply initiated to zero. The actual value is recieved in the program.

    int Nk=0;

    // in - it is the array that holds the plain text to be encrypted.

    // out - it is the array that holds the output CipherText after encryption.

    // state - the array that holds the intermediate results during encryption.

    char in[64], out[16], state[4][4];

    // The array that stores the round keys.

    char RoundKey[240];

    // The Key input to the AES Program

    char Key[32];

    int getSBoxValue(int num)
    {

     int sbox[256] =   {

//0     1    2      3     4    5     6     7      8    9     A      B    C     D     E     F

0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76, //0

0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0, //1

0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15, //2

0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75, //3

0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84, //4

0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf, //5

0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8, //6

0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2, //7

0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73, //8

0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb, //9

0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79, //A

0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08, //B

0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a, //C

0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e, //D

0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf, //E

0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16 }; //F

    return sbox[num];
    }

    // The round constant word array, Rcon[i], contains the values given by

    // x to th e power (i-1) being powers of x (x is denoted as {02}) in the field GF(28)

    // Note that i starts at 1, not 0).

    int Rcon[255] = {

0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a,

0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39,

0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a,

0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8,

0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef,

0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc,

0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b,

0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3,

0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94,

0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20,

0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63, 0xc6, 0x97, 0x35,

0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f,

0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb, 0x8d, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04,

0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x4d, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x5e, 0xbc, 0x63,

0xc6, 0x97, 0x35, 0x6a, 0xd4, 0xb3, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0xef, 0xc5, 0x91, 0x39, 0x72, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0xbd,

0x61, 0xc2, 0x9f, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x94, 0x33, 0x66, 0xcc, 0x83, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0x74, 0xe8, 0xcb  };

    // This function produces Nb(Nr+1) round keys. The round keys are used in each round to encrypt the states.

    void KeyExpansion()
    {

    int i,j;

    char temp[4],k;

    // The first round key is the key itself.

    for(i=0;i<Nk;i++)
    {

     RoundKey[i*4]=Key[i*4];

     RoundKey[i*4+1]=Key[i*4+1];

     RoundKey[i*4+2]=Key[i*4+2];

     RoundKey[i*4+3]=Key[i*4+3];

     }

     // All other round keys are found from the previous round keys.

     while (i < (Nb * (Nr+1)))
     {
     for(j=0;j<4;j++)
     {
        temp[j]=RoundKey[(i-1) * 4 + j];
     }

     if (i % Nk == 0)
     {

        // This function rotates the 4 bytes in a word to the left once.

        // [a0,a1,a2,a3] becomes [a1,a2,a3,a0]

        // Function RotWord()

        {

            k = temp[0];

            temp[0] = temp[1];

            temp[1] = temp[2];

            temp[2] = temp[3];

            temp[3] = k;

        }

        // SubWord() is a function that takes a four-byte input word and

        // applies the S-box to each of the four bytes to produce an output word.

        // Function Subword()

        {

            temp[0]=getSBoxValue(temp[0]);

            temp[1]=getSBoxValue(temp[1]);

            temp[2]=getSBoxValue(temp[2]);

            temp[3]=getSBoxValue(temp[3]);

            }

            temp[0] =  temp[0] ^ Rcon[i/Nk];
            }

            else if (Nk > 6 && i % Nk == 4)
            {

            // Function Subword()
            {
            temp[0]=getSBoxValue(temp[0]);

            temp[1]=getSBoxValue(temp[1]);

            temp[2]=getSBoxValue(temp[2]);

            temp[3]=getSBoxValue(temp[3]);

            }
            }

            RoundKey[i*4+0] = RoundKey[(i-Nk)*4+0] ^ temp[0];

            RoundKey[i*4+1] = RoundKey[(i-Nk)*4+1] ^ temp[1];

            RoundKey[i*4+2] = RoundKey[(i-Nk)*4+2] ^ temp[2];

            RoundKey[i*4+3] = RoundKey[(i-Nk)*4+3] ^ temp[3];

             i++;

            }

             }

           // This function adds the round key to state.

           // The round key is added to the state by an XOR function.

           void AddRoundKey(int round)
           {

           int i,j;

           for(i=0;i<4;i++)
           {

           for(j=0;j<4;j++)
           {
           state[j][i] ^= RoundKey[round * Nb * 4 + i * Nb + j];
           }
           }
           }

           // The SubBytes Function Substitutes the values in the

           // state matrix with values in an S-box.

           void SubBytes()

           {

           int i,j;

           for(i=0;i<4;i++)

           {

           for(j=0;j<4;j++)

           {

           state[i][j] = getSBoxValue(state[i][j]);

           }

           }

           }

         // The ShiftRows() function shifts the rows in the state to the left.

         // Each row is shifted with different offset.

         // Offset = Row number. So the first row is not shifted.

        void ShiftRows()

         {

        char temp;

// Rotate first row 1 columns to left

temp=state[1][0];

state[1][0]=state[1][1];

state[1][1]=state[1][2];

state[1][2]=state[1][3];

state[1][3]=temp;

// Rotate second row 2 columns to left

temp=state[2][0];

state[2][0]=state[2][2];

state[2][2]=temp;

temp=state[2][1];

state[2][1]=state[2][3];

state[2][3]=temp;

// Rotate third row 3 columns to left

temp=state[3][0];

state[3][0]=state[3][3];

state[3][3]=state[3][2];

state[3][2]=state[3][1];

state[3][1]=temp;

 }

      // xtime is a macro that finds the product of {02} and the argument to xtime modulo {1b}

      #define xtime(x)   ((x<<1) ^ (((x>>7) & 1) * 0x1b))
      void MixColumns()

       {

       int i;

       char Tmp,Tm,t;

       for(i=0;i<4;i++)

       {

        t=state[0][i];

         Tmp = state[0][i] ^ state[1][i] ^ state[2][i] ^ state[3][i] ;

         Tm = state[0][i] ^ state[1][i] ; Tm = xtime(Tm); state[0][i] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;

         Tm = state[1][i] ^ state[2][i] ; Tm = xtime(Tm); state[1][i] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;

         Tm = state[2][i] ^ state[3][i] ; Tm = xtime(Tm); state[2][i] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;

         Tm = state[3][i] ^ t ; Tm = xtime(Tm); state[3][i] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;

          }

         }

       // Cipher is the main function that encrypts the PlainText.

      void Cipher()

         {

int i,j,round=0;

//Copy the input PlainText to state array.

for(i=0;i<4;i++)

{

    for(j=0;j<4;j++)

    {

        state[j][i] = in[i*4 + j];

    }

}

// Add the First round key to the state before starting the rounds.

AddRoundKey(0);

// There will be Nr rounds.

// The first Nr-1 rounds are identical.

// These Nr-1 rounds are executed in the loop below.

for(round=1;round<Nr;round++)

{

    SubBytes();

    ShiftRows();

    MixColumns();

    AddRoundKey(round);

}

// The last round is given below.

// The MixColumns function is not here in the last round.

SubBytes();

ShiftRows();

AddRoundKey(Nr);

// The encryption process is over.

// Copy the state array to output array.

for(i=0;i<4;i++)

{

    for(j=0;j<4;j++)

    {

        out[i*4+j]=state[j][i];

    }

    }

    }



    int main()
    {
    printf("\n*******************AES Encryption Implementation******************\n");
    printf("\n******************************************************************\n");

    int i;

    // Receive the length of key here.

    while(Nr!=128 && Nr!=192 && Nr!=256)

    {

    printf("\nEnter the length of Key  (128, 192 or 256 only): ");

    scanf("%d",&Nr);

     }

    // Calculate Nk and Nr from the received value.

    Nk = Nr / 32;

    Nr = Nk + 6;

    printf("\nEnter the Key in hexadecimal: \n");

    for(i=0;i<Nk*4;i++)
    {
    scanf("%x",&Key[i]);
    }

   char ch, file_name[25];
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
   gets(file_name);

   fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

   if( fp == NULL )
   {
   perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

   char sig[64];

   int j=0;
   int c;
   char *pstr=in;
   printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);
   for (i=1;i<=(sizeof(sig)/16);i++)
   {  
   while(j<16*i)
   {
          fscanf(fp,"%c",&sig[j]);
          sprintf(pstr,"%02x",sig[j]);
          sscanf(pstr,"%02x",&in[j]); 
          pstr+=2;    
          printf("\nPlaintext:\n%02x ",in[j]);            
          j++;
          }            

          // The KeyExpansion routine must be called before encryption.


          KeyExpansion();


          // The next function call encrypts the PlainText with the Key using AES    algorithm.


           Cipher();

// Output the encrypted text.


           printf("\nText after encryption:\n");

           for(c=0;c<Nk*4;c++)
           {
           printf("\n%02x ",out[c]);
           }
           }

           fclose(fp);

           printf("\n\n");     
           getche();
            }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have proper includes and there are several mistakes ... run a debugger and you will get that .

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well the problem you are trying to describe, but as you describe it sounds like a segmentation fault while iterating over your `Key[]` array. What type of data is it?

Edit (as OP updated question):

`scanf("%x", ...)` expects `unsigned int *` (usually 32 bytes long) as a type, while you are providing `char *` (1 byte). Since you are using `char Key[32]`, I think that just using something like `unsigned int Key` would suffice.

Comment: Its a cipher key in hexadecimal. 16 hex values (32 hex digits) are entered by user

Comment: @user2503061 Is it declared any where ?

Comment: Yes it is declared before main. Its a global array.

Comment: @user2503061 Show the whole code, make sure that `file_name` is there in your directory

Comment: @user2503061 Updated my answer as more information was provided.

Comment: Now the out array is not giving the right output. It is also declared globally with array size of 16

Comment: So the original problem was solved. Now, about the new problem that arises... the code where you copy the states to the output array look suspicious, maybe you are not copying it in the right order, but I have to do more research about AES to fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<Nk*4;i++)
{
scanf("%x",&Key[i]);
}
```

Before getting the filename, you must consume the newline from the stdin. While entering the digits, you enter 1 hex digit per line. So after reading all the Nk*4 digits, there is a newline which is waiting to be consumed. The next statement to get the newline is `gets` function. It assumes that it has read the filename. The filename obviously does not exist because its empty. The fix is to consume the newline before getting the filename(See snippet)

I am not sure what kind of operations `Key` undergoes. But it must be a `unsigned int` if it is going to accept hex digits. `gets` is not recommended. Use `fgets` instead.

Here's a sample snippet you *could* have posted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int hex[32]={0} ;
    char line[BUFSIZ] = "";
    char filename[64] = "";
    int i;

    printf("Enter 4 hex digits:");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf(">");
        scanf("%x", &hex[i]);
    }    

    printf("The hex digits are:");    
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        printf("%x", hex[i]);
    /* Consume newline */
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

    printf("Enter filename with full path");
    if (fgets(filename, sizeof filename, stdin)) {
        size_t len = strlen(filename); /* has a newline in the end */
        filename[len - 1] = '\0';

        printf("Filename was %s\n", filename);
    } else {
       puts("Cannot read filename");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still the problem is there. I have used this code also but still the output disappears

Comment: You have statements like `fscanf(fp,"%c",&sig[j]);` after that. I am not sure if you understand what you are doing. Take a step back and please consider refactoring your code.

Comment: @PHlfounder This code is working fine separately but when I place it into my code, the output disappears just after getting the key. Showing the same bahaviour as before. Not getting the problem with my code. Please clarify

Comment: If there is problem with fscanf statement, the program should atleast ask to enter name of file. However it exits after getting key only

Comment: @user2503061 Before getting the filename include these lines `char line[BUFSIZ]; fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);`. Go through my code snippet and edit your program.

Comment: Already done this and solved the problem. Thank you so much @bsd

Comment: i did not write BUFSIZ before, so could not solve the problem. What is BUFSIZ ? @bsd

Comment: Constant define in `stdio.h` which is used as the size of buffer in stream I/O. It is at least 256 and varies from system to system.